# Sharing pricing information as a customer

Tags: united-states, business, competition, confidentiality

I am getting pricing quotes from two companies, A and B. The sales representative of company A asked me to send them the quote from company B, so that they can talk their management into offering me a better price. However, the quote from company B mentions "this information is confidential, it is illegal to share this document", or something along those lines. I do not intend to send the quote, for ethical reasons.

I am wondering whether the legal warnings on company B's documents are valid, which brings me to my question:

*Is it illegal for me, as a customer (not working for company A), to forward the pricing information sent to me by company B to their competitor?*

And if so, *why do people bother writing non-disclosure agreements if a simple line at the bottom of any piece paper can effectively protect the information contained on a document?*

My naive guess would be that the information stops being confidential when it is sent to someone who has no legal ties to the company, but I assume there is more to it than this...

Comment: You didn't sign an NDA with company A, so there isn't anything that prevents you from sharing any information. I believe its a deterrent, similar to email signature with a "warning".

Comment: This depends... If you are soliciting bids for a government procurement, sharing bid information with the competitor may be illegal. If the document contains any proprietary information (which pricing information falls under), then it may also be illegal. Bid tailoring and bid sharing are actually a type of fraud under government procurement guidelines.

Comment: But you'll sign an agreement when entering the government bidding program. This fella here is describing a private, personal process, outside of any procurement program.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul yes, i think RonBeyer comment and answer reverse the relationship.  He is basing it on the law which seems to allow a customer to treat the quote they receive as their (customer's) trade secret.  But he hasn't (so far) shown that there is any obligation on the customer's part to treat this as the provider's secret (unless there is a prior agreement to do so).